# Dynamic Method invocation (Objects and reference in inheritance )

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, dynamic

Suppose I have 2 classes ........`A` Class is base class and class `B` is derived class and if i create a reference such as : `A a=new B();` does it mean that reference `a` points to object of `B Class` ? If yes than how am i able to call overridden methods of A in B and not other methods of B ? thank you in advance

```
class A {
    m1() {
    }
}

class B extends A {
    m1() {
    }

    m2() {
    }
}


 A a=new B();
 a.m1(); //it will call overridden m1() in B 
 a.m2(); //it doesnt work if reference "a" points to object of B than why doesnt it call         m2 method ?
```

Comment: I suggest you read the Oracle Tutorial on [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: and of course, there's ((B)a).m2()

Comment: notice that for attributes instead of methods, it's a whole different story :-)

Comment: @Leo  how is it different in case of attributes if you could explain it  would be thankful :)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you so much dude ...reading it now

Comment: @VaibhavVaghela http://pastebin.com/3BV7YnH2

Comment: Yes, it is a reference to a `B`. The compiler doesn't know that, because you specifically said it was a reference to an `A`. So it only lets you use `A` methods (because otherwise what if it really was an `A` and it let you use `B` methods?)

Comment: Consider: should this compile? `void doStuff(A a1) {A a2 = a1; a2.m2();}`

Comment: @immibis i dont think it will compile ! a2 reference is also of type A so No it wont compile .....

Comment: @VaibhavVaghela so, if `A a2 = a1; a2.m2();` (where a1 is a parameter) doesn't compile, would you expect `A a1 = new B(); A a2 = a1; a2.m2();` to compile (given that the last two statements are the same)? Then what about `A a2 = new B(); a2.m2();`?

Comment: @immibis a2.m1(); will compile and run successfully but a2.m2 wont ....Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Oops, I meant a2.m2() in both cases.

Comment: @immibis Nope none of the 2 will compile coz at the end of the day compiler isnt aware of method m2(); as a2,a1 both are references of type "A"

Comment: Now you understand the reason. I think. Or maybe you understood it before and I'm just annoying you...

Comment: @immibis lol its fine dude but i still dont get the meaning of reference type of A .... What does it mean ? reference type of class "A" or of class "B" i get that new A() creates a object of class "A" which contains datefields and methods but what does it mean to be a reference type of any class :(

Comment: @VaibhavVaghela you might want to ask that as a new question, since it's about something different.

Comment: @immibis ya sorry bro :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Animal a=new Dog(); // Animal is parent - class, Dog is a child
```

means, you have an animal reference pointing to a Dog Object. So, only the methods which are declared in the parent class (Animal) can be called using a *parent- class reference*.

In your case, `m2()` is not defined in `Class A`, it is only defined in `class B` so, using a reference of `A`, you can't call `m2()`

Comment: "and overridden in the child Class (Dog)" This is not necessary. You can call method in `Animal` which are not overridden by `Dog`.

Comment: Here's a suggested edit that might make your meaning more clear (and more concise).

Comment: Botomline is you can call method of Animal class but not the methods of Dog class if your reference variable is of type Animal

Answer (score 2):

> If yes than how am i able to call overridden methods of A in B and not other methods of B

Because the reference is of type `A`. The compiler can only enforce calling the methods from this type.

Comment: okay i think i got it so its not exactly like the way i thought ! I thought that reference variable points to the object so any method can be called but reference variable is of type A so the compiler is not aware about any other methods other than that of A's