# Reference of a Class ? How does it workout in memory?

Tags: java

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

A a01 = new A();
A a02 = new B();
```

What difference this reference `a02` has compared to `a01`?

What does it mean for a reference to be of type `class A` or `class B`?

How does it work out in memory?

Comment: I think that was addressed in your preceeding question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468867/dynamic-method-invocation-objects-and-reference-in-inheritance What do you need more?

Comment: @JonatanCloutier No sir sorry but i dont get how does reference of a class work in memory that question was about polymorphism / dynamic method invocation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between `a01` and `a02`. Both are references of type `A`. This means that you can only use members of class `A` and not of any of its subtypes.

> what does reference of type class A or class B means ?

The reference type is determined by the declaration of the reference variable:

```
A a; // This is a reference of type A
B b; // This is a reference of type B
```

> is it such that if reference is of type class A it automatically points to object of class A

Yes, a reference of type `A` **must** point to an object of type `A`, but it also **may** point to any object that has a subclass of `A` for its type. In your example, a `B` **is a** `A` because `B extends A`.

Comment: as such when we say new A(); it creates object of class A rite ? and that object contains data fields and methods of Object of class A .... similarly what does reference of type class A or class B means ? how are both references different ? is it such that if reference is of type class A it automatically points to object of class A ?

Comment: @VaibhavVaghela You may want to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for some more information.

Comment: Well ! Just did thanks a lot Just +rep if possible it would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It is important to distinguish between the *declared type* of a variable, and the *runtime class* of an object.

In Java, each object has a *runtime class*, as specified in the class instance (or array ) creation expression that created it. The runtime stores this information in the object itself, enabling us to query it with the `instanceof` operator or the `getClass()` method.

In addition, each variable has a declared type. Declared types are used at *compile time* to verify that the variables support the operators, fields and methods the code uses on them. To do this, the compiler and runtime collaborate to enforce that a variable declared with reference type D either references null, or an object whose runtime class is D or a subtype of D at all times (excepting a few pathological corner cases arising from incorrect use of generic types).

In memory, your code would look something like this:

```
+-------+-------+
|  a01  |  a02  |       thread call stack
+-------+-------+
    |       |
    |       |
    v       v
+-----+  +-----+
|  A  |  |  B  |        object heap
+-----+  +-----+
```

Comment: Crystal Clear explanation ! now i understand the actual difference between reference type declaration at compile time and object creation at runtime ! thanks for your help sir

Answer (score 0):

In this example Class A is your parent class and Class B is child class you might be knowing that, Basically your child class knows about your parent class. But parent class does not know how many child classes has extended its functionality. So basically you can use Parent class as reference to hold child class object but child class can not hold parent class object. In your case both of the object has reference of Class A which does not make any difference. JVM will reserve memory for the object in the heap and provide reference in respective object reference. At the compile it doesn't make any difference but at the runtime it will call respective method of the object.

Comment: i guess i got what you are trying to say !!!!! and what if the reference was of type B ? how would it differ from reference of type A ?

Comment: @Vaibhav - If the reference is of type B then it can hold only class B object or any class inherited Class B and in the later case reference of type A can hold both Class A and B object. You can go through java inheritance if you want more clarification.